# JDBC URL connection to SQL Server using Windows Authentication in JIRA plugin

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jira, windows-authentication, jira-plugin

I am currently at my wits end. I am trying to connect a JIRA plugin (Atlassian Java SDK) to a SQL Server 2012 database. It's required that I use Windows Authentication, but JIRA is logging:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

I've read that this can be combatted by adding the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file to the program's library path, but there are no references specifically for JIRA plugins on how to do this other than for the base JIRA `dbconfig.xml`, which I am not using. This is a connection made within the plugin using the code:

```
String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:1433;databaseName=%s;integratedSecurity=true;domain=XXXX;", server, database);
```

I have tried to add the dll file to the following locations, all to no avail:

- `C:/{JIRA INSTALL PATH}/bin`
- `C:/{JIRA INSTALL PATH}/jre/bin`
- `C:/{JAVA INSTALL PATH}/jre_8.x.x/bin`

What gives?

**UPDATE:**
I have gone in and added the JDBC JAR/DLL to the classpath/library path respectively in the JIRA Windows service configuration tool. Still getting the same error.

[image: JIRA Windows Service Configuration Tool]

**UPDATE 2:**
I have switched to using the JTDS driver to see if JIRA was just not able to use the standard JDBC driver for some reason, but getting a similar error:

> java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.

I have also created a new Java app to test this in a controlled environment, but do not get this error after adding the `ntlmauth.dll` file to the `C:\Windows\System32` directory. This leads me to believe this may be a bug within JIRA or I have something configured improperly.

Comment: without jira you can connect normally to that db using jdbc?

Comment: Exactly what did you configure, because your screenshot doesn't show the actual values used. Note that 1) `java.library.path` must point to a **folder**, 2) the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (auth, not ath) comes in a 32 bit and a 64 bit variant. Which one you need to use depends on the JVM used, And 3) the user running JIRA might be a local system account that can't use Windows authentication against your SQL Server (although that would result in a different error IIRC).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, `java.library.path` is pointing  to the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\x64` folder and not the dll. The JVM that JIRA uses is the 64-bit version, as that's the version of JIRA/Java I have installed.

Comment: @Daniel yes, this works fine when I try it within a new java project and add the jdbc driver to the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my own conclusion after many weeks of searching:

It is (currently) impossible to do this without the use of a password (which is sometimes the entire point of using Windows/Active Directory credentials). You can however use the JTDS driver in junction with a domain, username, and password to authenticate to servers that require windows authentication. This does not solve the core issue, but from what I can tell is the only current solution close enough to it.